# solaris python setuptools install

Tags: python, solaris, setuptools, distutils

I have a solaris host:

```
SunOS blah 5.10 Generic_147441-27 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

and I have python at `/usr/bin/python`

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jun 26 2012, 21:27:36) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

the problem is that I do not appear to have setuptools installed, so I download the tarball and try:

```
setuptools-0.6c12dev-r88846$ /usr/bin/python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from distutils.util import convert_path
ImportError: No module named distutils.util
```

and of course, because I don't have distutils, I can't install... well anything.

I'm not familiar with solaris at all; some googling indicated that I need python-dev installed. how do I do that? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python from OpenCSW. There you'll get a Python package and many modules, including setuptools. Available Python versions are Python 2.6 (`CSWpython`), 2.7 (`CSWpython27`) and 3.3 (`CSWpython33`). Most module packages are available for Python 2.6 and 2.7. Assuming you've [got started with OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html) and added `/opt/csw/bin` to `PATH`, you can:

```
sudo pkgutil -y -i python py_django
```

To get modules for Python 3.3, can use virtualenv and pip as a regular user. For example:

```
sudo pkgutil -y -i python33 virtualenv
virtualenv -p /opt/csw/bin/python3.3 py3env
source py3env/bin/activate
pip install django
```